# int value changed unexpected

Tags: c, int, cgi

I meet a problem of a c program: the int variable is changed unexpected.

Below is all about the problem:

I try to read a txt file which looks like:

```
2013/12/31 19:53:54, started, /activeJob/start/ Failed
2013/12/31 19:55:55, ended, retCode = 6, Couldn't resolve host name, /activeJob/finish/ Failed
2014/01/01 08:06:55, started, /activeJob/start/ Failed
2014/03/04 12:16:55, started, /activeJob/start/ Success
2014/03/04 12:17:25, ended, retCode = 0, No error, /activeJob/finish/ success
2014/03/04 13:57:21, started, /activeJob/start/ Success
```

It is a log file which will record the start/finish time of a task. I want to parse the log file and find the finished task record in a order time(latest first). For example, I will try to read the last line and it shows that the task is running. Hence I ignore it and continue to read the last 2nd line. In general the next two line which has "ended" and "started" in pairs can be marked as a record.

My environment is: Centos6.5 (installed via VMWaire). 
Below is the source code and it uses   libccgi:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include "json/json.h"
#include "ccgi.h"
#include  <errno.h>

const char *queryName = "account";
const char *queryPage = "pageIndex";
const char *startAction = "/activeJob/start/";
const char *finishAction = "/activeJob/finish/";
const char *contentDes[] = {"there is backup processing, start at :","there is no backup"};
const float pageNums = 8.0;



const char * jsonStringCreate(json_object *jsonObj,int statueCode, char *content, int totalPages)
{
    json_object_object_add(jsonObj, "statueCode", json_object_new_int(statueCode));
    json_object_object_add(jsonObj, "content", json_object_new_string(content));
    json_object_object_add(jsonObj, "totalPages", json_object_new_int((int)totalPages));

    //the memory of returned string is under control of jsonObj
    return json_object_get_string(jsonObj);
}

char *mallocString(char *string)
{
    char *returnString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1 + strlen(string)));
    strcpy(returnString, string);
    //owner free the returned string
    return returnString;
}


/* File must be open with 'b' in the mode parameter to fopen() */
/* Set file position to size of file before reading last line of file */
char* fgetsr(char* buf, int n, FILE* binaryStream)
{
  long fpos;
  int cpos;
  int first = 1;

  if (n &lt; 1 || (fpos = ftell(binaryStream)) == -1 || fpos == 0)
    return NULL;

  cpos = n - 1;
  buf[cpos] = '\0';

  for (;;)
  {
    int c;

    if (fseek(binaryStream, --fpos, SEEK_SET) != 0 ||
        (c = fgetc(binaryStream)) == EOF)
      return NULL;

    if (c == '\n' && first == 0) /* accept at most one '\n' */
      break;
    first = 0;

    if (c != '\r') /* ignore DOS/Windows '\r' */
    {
      unsigned char ch = c;
      if (cpos == 0)
      {
        memmove(buf + 1, buf, n - 2);
        ++cpos;
      }
      memcpy(buf + --cpos, &ch, 1);
    }

    if (fpos == 0)
    {
      fseek(binaryStream, 0, SEEK_SET);
      break;
    }
  }

  memmove(buf, buf + cpos, n - cpos);

  return buf;
}

</code></pre>
<pre><code>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[], char **env)
{
    int statueCode = 0;
    int totalPages = 0;
    char *content = NULL;
    json_object *jsonObj = json_object_new_object();

    printf("Content-type: text/plain; encoding=utf-8\n\n");

    CGI_varlist *vl;
    const char *name;
    CGI_value *value;
    int i;

    if ((vl = CGI_get_all("/tmp/cgi-upload-XXXXXX") ) == 0)
    {
        // CGI error
        // fputs("CGI_get_all() failed\r\n", stdout);
        statueCode = 501;
        content = mallocString("CGI error");

    }
    else
    {
        //get the CGI env parameters, next to get the query parameter
        char *accountName = NULL;
        int queryIndex = -1;
        for (name = CGI_first_name(vl); name != 0; name = CGI_next_name(vl))
        {
            value = CGI_lookup_all(vl, 0);
            for ( i = 0; value[i] != 0; ++i)
            {

                if (strcmp(name, queryName) == 0)
                {
                    accountName = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value[i]) + 4 + 1));
                    strcpy(accountName, value[i]);
                    strcat(accountName, ".log");
                }
                else if (strcmp(name, queryPage) == 0)
                {
                    queryIndex = atoi(value[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (accountName == NULL || queryIndex &lt; 0)
        {
            statueCode = 502;
            content = mallocString("wrong query parameters format");
        }
        else
        {
            //for test, need remove
            FILE *logFile = fopen("./test@mail.com.log", "rb");
            // FILE *logFile = fopen(accountName, "r");
            char *lastLineStr = NULL;
            int lineNum = 0;

            if (logFile != NULL)
            {
                //log file is found

                char *line = NULL;
                size_t len = 0;
                ssize_t read;
                while( (read = getline(&line, &len, logFile)) != -1)
                {
                    // printf("%s\n", line);
                    if (strstr(line, finishAction) != 0)
                    {
                        /* code */
                        totalPages ++;
                    }
                    lineNum ++;
                }
                free(line);

                int realPage = ceil(totalPages/pageNums);
                if (queryIndex > realPage)
                {
                    /* code */
                    statueCode = 503;
                    content = mallocString("wrong parameter: query index is beyond the total page");
                }
                else
                {
                    //log file exist and query index is valid
                    long startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0, currentIndex = 0;;
                    startIndex = (queryIndex - 1) * pageNums;
                    endIndex = (queryIndex) *pageNums;

                    currentIndex = startIndex;

                    char buf[256];
                    int isFinishFound = -1;
                    int  isStartFound = -1;
                    char *finishContetn[] = {};
                    char *startContent[] = {};
// this is the core part
                    while(fgetsr(buf, sizeof(buf), logFile) != NULL && currentIndex lt; endIndex)
                    {
                        if (strstr(buf, finishAction) != 0)
                        {
                            /* code */
                            if (isFinishFound &gt; 0)
                            {
                                /* code */
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isFinishFound = 1; 
                                isStartFound = -1;
                                finishContetn[currentIndex] = mallocString(buf);

                            }

                        }// strange part:
                        else if (strstr(buf, startAction) != 0)
                        {
                            //finish is not found, means: a start with no finish pairs
                            if (isFinishFound &lt; 0)
                            {
                                /* code */
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                if (isStartFound &lt; 0)
                                {
                                    /* code */
                                    startContent[currentIndex] = mallocString(buf);
                                    isStartFound = 1;
                                    isFinishFound = -1;
                                    currentIndex ++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }


            }
            else
            {
                //log file is not found
                statueCode = 400;
                content = mallocString("not found the account log");

                // printf("not found\n");
                // fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
            }
            if (logFile)
            {
                fclose(logFile);
            }

        }



    }

    return 0;
}
```

The libjson and libccgi is placed in the right place and I build and make it like:

```
/usr/local/bin/clang -I /usr/include -DHAVE_SSL -DCLDMAN -DCLDMAN_USE_RETRY -DUSE_PROXY -c -MMD -fPIC -g -DHAVE_SSL -DCLDMAN -I../../build/include -I../../build/include/curl -I../../build/include/json -I../../build/include/svmdisk -o getLog.o getLog.c
/usr/local/bin/clang -o getLog getLog.o -L../../build/lib -lm -lccgi  -ljson
```

and it has no error in the terminal.

The problem I met is the value of int `isStartFound` will has a strange value of 134538336. It happen when I debug as following:

1. in the while, the currentIndex=1 which means it begins to find the second record
2. it finds the "finish", and it begins to do:

   ```
   isFinishFound = 1; 
   isStartFound = -1;
   finishContetn[currentIndex] = mallocString(buf);
   ```
3. After that, it runs to the `while` again, and now the `isStartFound` is changed to `134538336`.

I also try to add `isStartFound` to the watch variable. And it also shows in the "strange part"(which I add in the code) the value of `isStartFound` changes from `-1` to `134538336`.

I can't find where this value comes from. I doubt that the way I build and link is wrong. But I failed to find it.

Could any one suggest the way how can I look into?

Thanks!

=======edited:
The problem mainly locates the code below:

```
char buf[256];
int isFinishFound = -1;
int  isStartFound = -1;
while(fgetsr(buf, sizeof(buf), logFile) != NULL && currentIndex  0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            isFinishFound = 1; 
            isStartFound = -1;
            finishContetn[currentIndex] = mallocString(buf);

        }

    }// here strange happens: the isStartFound changes!
    else
    {
        // other part
    }
}
```

`fgetsr` is used to read one line of the text; `isStartFound&isFinishFound` are 2 mask to show whether the "start"/"finish" record is found.

The problem comes with a precondition：the first record is found and now we are try to read the last 5th line(which is the 2nd line). The text file is :

```
2013/12/31 19:53:54, started, /activeJob/start/ Failed
2013/12/31 19:55:55, ended, retCode = 6, Couldn't resolve host name, /activeJob/finish/ Failed
2014/01/01 08:06:55, started, /activeJob/start/ Failed
2014/03/04 12:16:55, started, /activeJob/start/ Success
2014/03/04 12:17:25, ended, retCode = 0, No error, /activeJob/finish/ success
2014/03/04 13:57:21, started, /activeJob/start/ Success
```

Now it begins to  read the 2nd line and finds "finish", and hence it need to mark the var: isStartFound = -1.

When the program runs to the first "}", the isStartFound is -1. But when it runs to the second "}"(which is the "}" of `if (strstr(buf, finishAction) != 0)`), the value changes: `siStartFound = 134538336`!( I add comment in the code) As you can see, here nothing is done!

This is my question and where I feel it weird. (Sorry for the too long code. If this edition still troubles you, please tell me.)

Comment: So much code! An unexpected variable change is often due to accessing an array index out of its normal bounds.

Comment: Try to narrow down the code. One way of doing it is to step through the code in a debugger. First in bigger steps (stepping over functions), then as you narrow it down a little, you step into function and step line by line to see what happens, while keeping track of important variables (pointers, array indexes, loop conditions etc).

Comment: @Bathsheba,@Joachim, I make an edit at the bottom. pls~

Comment: Have a look at http://www.sscce.org/. Help us to help you.

Comment: *Bathsheba*'s comment referrs to a specific instance of the more general case of corrupted memory.

Comment: `finishContetn` and `startContent` are both zero length!

Comment: @Bathsheba, could you take a look at my edition at the bottom? thanks

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, will it have effect on the int isStartFound?

Comment: @scorpiozj Yes, since you haven't provided any space for them, assigning `finishContetn[0]` or `startContent[0]` is likely to overwrite `isStartFound`. See Joachim Pileborgs answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this declaration:

```
char *finishContetn[] = {};
```

This declares `finishContetn` as an *empty* array of pointers. Being empty, no matter what index you use to access this array, it will be out of bounds.

As you assign to this array:

```
finishContetn[currentIndex] = mallocString(buf);
```

you will write beyond the bounds, and will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In this case, you will overwrite the stack where other variables are located, like for example the `isStartFound` variable.

---

A way to solve this is to either set a fixed size, or to use a dynamic "array". The dynamic array solution requires you to declare the variable as a pointer to pointer (to  `char`) and use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to (re)allocate the array.

Something like

```
char **finishContent = NULL;
size_t finishContentSize = 0;  /* Current size of the array */

...

char **temp = realloc(finishContent, sizeof(finishContent[0]) * finishContentSize + 1);
if (temp != NULL)
{
    finishContent = temp;
    finishContent[finishContentSize++] = malloc(...);
}
```

Note that I use a temporary variable for the return of `realloc`, this is because if `realloc` fails then it won't free `finishContent` for you, and if you assign directly to `finishContent` you will loose your original pointer and can't `free` it later.

Also note that I use `sizeof(finishContent[0])`. This will work even when `finishContent` is `NULL` because `sizeof` is a pure compile-time operator, it will not create any run-time code.

You might of course need to modify the code to fit your application, but the above should be enough to give you an idea.

Comment: @scorpiozj Of course, you have the same problem with `startContent`.

Comment: yes, you're right. I realized the `startContent` and `finishContent` are not intialized. Thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just ran into the same problem, and was on the verge of asking my first question -- thankfully your answer was one of the autopopulated questions!